# The Adventure of Jack #1

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story, geography

> Jack's adventure starts at the top left of the table,
>
> Hey, Vietnamese money should be removed!
>
> So he adventures along to Rome, stopping for 50 minutes.
>
> And suddenly he's back at the corner of the table!
>
> So Jack carefully adds 1 minute to his timer,
>
> And is transported to a new location!

**What country is Jack in?**

Hint:

> From this statement, you will get a city, then find in which country that city is in.

Hint 2:

> In the clue "So Jack carefully adds one minute to his timer," you are adding multiple letters to what you already have.

Hint 3:

> The word **ONE** is what you are adding to Jack's timer.

I better not have to give you any more clues!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:

> The top left (as corrected) of the periodic table is HYDROGEN.

Hey, Vietnamese money should be removed!

> remove HEY (hey!) and DONG (Vietnamese money) to get R

So he adventures along to Rome, stopping for 50 minutes.

> The Roman 50 is L, so adding that gives RL

And suddenly he's back at the corner of the table!

> As per @Jafe, back (reverse) to the periodic table, LR (lawrencium)
>  (though is it really a corner?)

So Jack carefully adds 1 minute to his timer

> per hint 3, add ONE giving LR**ONE**, or perhaps L**O**R**NE**, which is a seaside village in Victoria Australia.

So Jack is in

> Australia.

Comment: The partial bit of your answer is correct. Think more about the wordplay. And yes, I meant top left. I will correct that right now.

Comment: (rot13)Vs ol lbhe ybtvp, na nqqvgvba bs 50 zvahgrf vf Y, gura fheryl na nqqvgvba bs 1 zvahgr jbhyq or V abg Z?

Comment: Vg vf abg V be Z. Naq lbh arrq gb guvax zber nobhg gur Ivrganzrfr zbarl. Gurer vf fgvyy fbzrguvat ryfr lbh arrq gb qb va gung fragrapr. (rot13)

Comment: I think the other corner is rot13[Ye be Ynjerapvhz]

Comment: @jafe, I thought of that, or rot13(Bt be Ur be Se sbe bgure cbffvoyr pbearef) but I'm not seeing how they help yet :(

Comment: It is the corner in my eyes. 
Also pay more attention to Hint 2.

Comment: Well done. You have finally figured out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jack has travelled to

> Costa Rica.

Jack's adventure starts at the top left of the table,

> At the top left of the periodic table is **HYDROGEN** (per @SteveV)

Hey, Vietnamese money should be removed!

> Removing the letters "hey dong" from hydrogen, we get **R** (per @SteveV)

So he adventures along to Rome, stopping for 50 minutes.

> Add the Roman numeral L (=50), making **LR**.

And suddenly he's back at the corner of the table!

> Lr is lawrencium, which is found at the bottom-right corner of the periodic table.

So Jack carefully adds 1 minute to his timer,

> According to hint #3, we're adding the word "one" to what we have. I'm going with L**o**r**ne**.

And is transported to a new location!

> Lorne is the name of a [couple of places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorne#Places), including a [town in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorne,_Victoria)

Comment: You are correct about everything up until the one minute part. Well done. But alas, it is not the correct answer. Jack is not in Costa Rica.

Comment: rot13 (Jbhyq nqqvat gur V va sebag or hfrshy? Znxvat vg VYE [Vybeva, Avtrevn])

Comment: @Kryesec Yeah, but according to hint #2 we're looking for multiple letters...

Comment: just spit balling but maybe try adding one how it is spelled in a different language