# Cassocks and castles

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> I start at one end of the table.
>   Replace my ending with a ton of ice, and I sip my beer.
>   Then remove my ending, and I sit in a Scandinavian castle.
>   Put a girl in between, and I walk around in my cassock.
>   Round out D and make a large centralization, and I'm in America.
>   An Odessa-hosted site replaces my middle.
>   Now I'm at the other end of the table.

What do you think is on the table?

Comment: Inspired by @aguy's [The Adventure of Jack #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75555).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now a complete answer, thanks to the clever idea of **@Chrone** in comments.

I start at one end of the table.

> [Carlsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_Carlsen) (Magnus), current wold champion busy defending his title in a very tense [match](https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2018-wcc) in London.

Replace my ending with a ton of ice, and I sip my beer.

> The ton of ice must be an iceberg (although this is much heavier than a ton), and a **Carlsberg** is a Danish beer. (Karlsberg is also a german beer, but much less to my taste).

Then remove my ending, and I sit in a Scandinavian castle.

> We remove 'sberg' and we get **Carl**, king of Sweden. Which one ? [Pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_of_Sweden) your favorite.

Put a girl in between, and I walk around in my cassock.

> Dina is a girl's firstname, and a **Cardinal** wears a cassock.

Round out D and make a large centralization, and I'm in America.

> D rounded is an O, then the 'l' gets centralized and we get **Carolina**, the name of two US states.

An Odessa-hosted site replaces my middle.

> The domain name for Ukrainian websites is .ua, which we put in the middle in place of 'oli' to get:

Now I'm at the other end of the table.

> [Caruana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabiano_Caruana) (Fabiano), Carlsen's challenger in the World Championship, conveniently sitting at the other end of the chess table.

What do you think is on the table?

> A chessboard, a chess clock, some papers and pens, a lot of [bottles](https://wctour.s3.amazonaws.com/media/news_images/42fafe677ca0f2b1.jpg) of water, and 32-chess pieces - including bishops (wearing cassocks) and rooks (aka castles).

Comment: I think it's rot13[(Zntahf) Pneyfra <--> (Snovb) Pnehnan, gjb purffznfgref fvggvat ng gur bccbfvgr fvqr bs rnpu bgure ng gur purff gnoyr. (.HN) vf Hxenvavna qbznva.] Fits the title too.

Comment: Sorry, typo. *r13(Snovnab)

Comment: Nice work, guys! This is the intended answer.